# How to populate spinner from SQL Server database in WCF? (Xamarin Android)

Tags: android, wcf, xamarin, spinner, android-spinner

In my web service, I have this code to get the location:

```
public string DisplayLocation(EmployeeDetails location)
{
    InsertToFSRDataContext context = new InsertToFSRDataContext();

    var loc = from z in context.Parameters where z.ParamGroup == "LOCATION" orderby z.ParamValue ascending select z.ParamDesc;
    var loca = loc.FirstOrDefault();
    string returnLoca = Convert.ToString(loca);

    return returnLoca; 
}
```

The above code is wrong. How can return it into a list or array?

In my activity, I have the following for populating the data into the spinner (this is wrong but how do I do this properly?).

```
    private void ClientOnDisplayLocationCompleted(object sender, DisplayLocationCompletedEventArgs displayLocationCompletedEventArgs)
    {
        string msg = null;
        if (displayLocationCompletedEventArgs.Error != null)
        {
            // code
        }
        else if (displayLocationCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled)
        {
            // code
        }
        else
        {
            msg = displayLocationCompletedEventArgs.Result;

            List<String> list = Resources.GetStringArray(msg).ToList(); // this is incorrect

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Resource.Drawable.spinner_item, list);

            spinner1.Adapter = adapter1;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<string> DisplayLocation(EmployeeDetails location)
{
    InsertToFSRDataContext context = new InsertToFSRDataContext();

    var loc = from z in context.Parameters where z.ParamGroup == "LOCATION" orderby z.ParamValue ascending select z.ParamDesc;

    // this assumes that z.ParamDesc is a string
    return loc.ToList<string>(); 
}
```